# creating in matlab a fully opaque hexahedron

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I want to create a fully non-transparent hexahedron (a 6 faces 3d object, like a distorted cube) using the patch function. Below is my code, (make the 3 adjacent faces of point #1 and then the other 3 adjacent to its antipodal point and thus having all 6 "patched"). However, the transparency as you can see does not work as intended. Any idea why that happens, or any way to bypass the problem?

```
vec=[1,2,4,3,1;1,5,6,2,1;1,5,7,3,1];
vec2=[8,4,3,7,8;8 4 2 6 8;8 6 5 7 8];
cube = [0 0 0;0 0 1;0 1 0;0 1 1; 1 0 0; 1 0 1; 1 1 0; 1 1 1];
figure
patch('Faces',[vec(1,:),vec(2,:),vec(3,:)],'Vertices',cube,'FaceColor','white','FaceAlpha',1); axis equal; cameratoolbar;
hold on
patch('Faces',[vec2(1,:),vec2(2,:),vec2(3,:)],'Vertices',cube,'FaceColor','white','FaceAlpha',1); axis equal; cameratoolbar;
```

This is the figure produced:[image]

(Matlab 2017a).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You created the `vec` array in the right way, but you screwed it when handing it to the `patch()` function. You can concatenate `vec`and `vec2` in one variable. Then your code looks like this:

```
vec=[1,2,4,3,1;1,5,6,2,1;1,5,7,3,1; ...
     8,4,3,7,8;8 4 2 6 8;8 6 5 7 8];
cube = [0 0 0;0 0 1;0 1 0;0 1 1; 1 0 0; 1 0 1; 1 1 0; 1 1 1];
patch('Faces',vec,'Vertices',cube,'FaceColor','white','FaceAlpha',1);
axis equal
view(-41,33);
```

The result is shown here.
**Note: The left front side of the cube is *not* transparent on screen display. This is a bug of octaves figure to PNG export.**
[image: Cube drawn with script]

Comment: Elaborate a bit please. Do you mean that hold on ruins it? Could you write the sequence of points to make it with only one call?

Comment: Ok I figured that out